# SignalR on port 80/443

Tags: http, iis, websocket, signalr, firewall

I try to make a push service that runs on port 80 (or 443). These are the only ports that has inbound rules on firewall (for now).
My server is windows server 2008 r2 and has IIS installed on it.

The question is whether can I run my SignalR app with owin (self host) on port 80 ? Will it be confllicted with the IIS ? Or is it possible to run my signalr on top of IIS and thus my IT won't change firewall configuration? or, another possibility is to install another vm that has no IIS installed on it and then I can use port 80 freely?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely host SignalR application in IIS. It should be enough to just poblish finished application to website in IIS. SignalR wil then be located under this website.

Following this tutorial should be enough to get you started: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: And how do I access the push service in code?  What is the connection string?